# How to check compatibility of different JAR files without compiling (finding breaking API changes)

Tags: java

I have many JARs (50+) which will be developed and published separate.
There is also a deep dependency tree between these JARs.

A build system will collect these JARs in specific version together in one EAR. Not always the latest version of each JAR.

If there is a breaking API change in one of the JAR I want to find out who is using that API.

Automatic compiling all the JARs against the source code specific version of all depended JARs is difficult to implement in my current source code and build system structure.

Maybe there is another way to check that compatibility with the already compiled EAR?
All of these sources have the same package prefix. And a solution during runtime test would also help.

- jar A

  - jar B

    - jar E

      - jar H
      - jar I
  - jar C

    - jar F
  - jar D

    - jar G